# What does EAFFFFFE mean in ARM architecture

Tags: assembly, arm

I often see instruction EAFFFFFE(which means Branch to current PC address) when studying ARM architecture assembly.

What does it mean and why is it needed to branch to current PC address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A branch to the current address will be generated by, for example,

```
while(1);
```

or

```
for(;;);
```

in C.  Both of these loops run forever, doing nothing.

Why would you want this?  Well, in production code, you probably wouldn't.  But in example or test code, it's quite common to reach the 'end' of a running program.  What should the CPU do then?  It is possible to halt most CPUs to save power, but this is hardly necessary when running simple test code, and anyway it often interacts poorly with debuggers.  Entering an infinite loop is the simplest way to get the CPU to do 'nothing'.

(I've taken your word for it that `EAFFFFFE` is what you say it is - you don't specify an ARM architecture or instruction set.)